# How to generate date time format in Javascript same as ""Wed Dec 08 2021 19:05:48 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)"

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, utc

I'm using `moment.js` to generate a date time string in `NodeJS`, but I don't know how to make it include `(Coordinated Universal Time)` at the end. Please help me. Thanks!

```
const moment = require('moment');

console.log(moment.utc().toString()); 
// result: Wed Mar 16 2022 11:07:40 GMT+0000 
// not include (Coordinated Universal Time)
// Expected: Wed Mar 16 2022 11:07:40 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `(Coordinated Universal Time)` at the end of the string logged:

```js
const moment = require('moment');

console.log(`${moment.utc().toString()} (Coordinated Universal Time)`);
// => Wed Mar 16 2022 11:07:40 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
```

Comment: Thank @ACGaming, but that's not the solution i was looking for